# Prove that a graph with $n$ vertices and at least $4n − 9$ edges has a $K_6$-minor.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

A graph $H$ is a minor of a graph $G$ if $H$ can be obtained from $G$ by a sequence of contractions and deletions of edges. We say that $G$ has an $H$-minor if $G$ has $H$ as a minor. The complete graph on $n$ vertices is denoted by $K_n$.

The following theorem is from what I read in the article: "Suzuki, Yusuke
$K_7$-minors in optimal 1-planar graphs. Discrete Math. 340, No. 6, 1227-1234 (2017)".

**Theorem**[Mader]  A graph with $n$ vertices and at least $4n − 9$ edges has a $K_6$-minor.

- W. Mader, Homomorphiesätze für Graphen, Math. Ann. 178 (1968) 154–168.

I would like to see the proof of the theorem, but  the original article is in German. I don't know where else I can see a proof (in English) of this theorem. Or it's easy to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of this theorem can be found in **[1]** (**Theorem 4**) by using induction on the number of vertices. The proof is quite different from the one given by Mader. That is why they include it in **Section 2** of this paper.

**[1]**: J. Campbell, T. W. Mattman, R. Ottman, J. Pyzer, M. Rodrigues, and
S. Williams. Intrinsic knotting and linking of almost complete graphs,
2007. URL https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701422.pdf